# PHP Mysql select query to order pairs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a customer database application for a dancing school.

I need to display an overview of all customers that are participating in the same dancing level. But I want the overview order by couples not by the customer ID.
For this I'm joining three tables (look at the query below)
Each customer has a unique ID in the tabel CRM_CONTACTS and also has in it's row a reference to his or her partner (PARTNER_ID).

Table CRM_CONTACTS

```
ID   CONTACTS_LNAME
1    VON KLOMPENBURG
2    Mc Donalds
3    MC Adams
4    Mr X
```

Then I have CRM_PRODUCTS
    ID    PRODUCTS_NAME
    1     Beginners
    2     intermediate
    3     advanced

Then the table in which I assign a product/level to a contact and also indicate his/her partner

```
ID   CONTACTS_ID    PRODUCTS_ID   PARTNER_ID
1    1              1             4
2    2              1             3
3    3              1             2
4    4              1             1
```

Now I would like to receive a list order by couple based on the parter_id
So for the beginners level I would get a list like this
1 VON KLOMPENBURG
2 Mr X
3 Mc Donalds
4 Mc Adams

Here's my select statement

```
 $result = mysqli_query($coni,"SELECT CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.ID, CONTACTS_ID, 
CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_NAME, 
CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_PRICE,CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PARTNER_ID, 
CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PARTNER_NAME, 
PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_REMARKS,PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_DISCOUNT, 
PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_PAIDBYBANK,PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_PAIDBYCASH, 
CRM_CONTACTS.CONTACTS_LNAME, CRM_CONTACTS.CONTACTS_FNAME 
FROM CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE
LEFT JOIN CRM_CONTACTS ON CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.CONTACTS_ID = CRM_CONTACTS.ID 
LEFT JOIN CRM_PRODUCTS ON CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PRODUCTS_ID = CRM_PRODUCTS.ID
WHERE CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PRODUCTS_ID = '". $PRODUCTS_ID . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($coni,"SELECT CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.ID, CONTACTS_ID, 
CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_NAME, 
CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_PRICE,CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PARTNER_ID, 
CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PARTNER_NAME, 
PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_REMARKS,PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_DISCOUNT, 
PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_PAIDBYBANK,PRODUCTS_PURCHASE_PAIDBYCASH, 

CRM_CONTACTS.CONTACTS_LNAME, CRM_CONTACTS.CONTACTS_FNAME 
FROM CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE
LEFT JOIN CRM_CONTACTS ON CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.CONTACTS_ID = CRM_CONTACTS.ID 
LEFT JOIN CRM_PRODUCTS ON CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PRODUCTS_ID = CRM_PRODUCTS.ID
WHERE CRM_PRODUCTS_PURCHASE.PRODUCTS_ID = '". $PRODUCTS_ID . "'
ORDER BY IF (ID < PARTNER_ID, ID, PARTNER_ID)");
```

And your customers will be ordered in couples.